# ilovepdf desktop leaves warning message

Tags: batch-file, conversion, vbscript, subtitles, com

ilovepdf desktop program shows the message "Your PDFs have been converted successfully" when the conversion process is completed while right-clicking on Windows. The question is, how to automatically close this pop-up warning message when the conversion is completed?

[image]

I would be happy if you help.

Comment: Merhaba! I recommend AutoIt

Comment: Thank you for the comment. So what kind of autoit code can do this?

Comment: You would probably need a loop https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_loops.htm and https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/PixelGetColor.htm to check if the button has appeared and then https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseClick.htm

Comment: Actually, I want it to close automatically when the conversion process is completed, not while the conversion process is in progress. It ends when the file is created. How can I query autoit when this file is created?

Comment: pdftk-server is a nice command line tool, it has tools like merge and splitting, it does not convert pdf to word or excel.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt you can write a script that checks the color of the pixel until it has turned orange, and clicks the button if it has

Comment: I would be happy if you help me, how can I write this code? Gantendo